# Moving jpg from 1 server to another using read/write in PHP

Tags: php

I need to move jpgs from my SERVER 1 to SERVER 2 ...

My solution for doing this is to do a simple, binary-safe read of the files on script 1 on Server 1 , putting the data in a curl object/array, and POST that as a regular post routine to a script on SERVER 2 which receives the array and does a file_put_contents() routine to write the jpg files accordingly... on success (when script on SERVER 2 returns "ok") then script 1 deletes the files..

I pretty much know how to do this using CURL and all, but I just wanted to know if anyone is opposed to this method, or have a better solution?

Regards

Comment: Is this a one time thing, or do you need to o this all the time?

Comment: all the time.. there's an HTML page kept open in the browser that runs a JS loop

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a lot of solutions that seem like they're probably better, including:

- [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)
- [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) / [sftp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp)
- [a netcat tar pipe](http://toast.djw.org.uk/tarpipe.html)
- If you're intent on using PHP, there's PHP's [ssh2](http://php.net/ssh2) extension, which includes an interface [scp](http://php.net/ssh2-scp-send) and one for [sftp](http://php.net/ssh2_sftp)

Comment: umm i need to CODE this solution and it needs to be triggered by JS.. basically i have an HTML page w/ JS on loop loading the Php script to check for new files to MOVE to server 2 .. i need minimal dependencies from 3rd party software and server modules.. trying to keep it as native php as possible...because im thinking about installing this system onto Android device via LAMP for android.. thanks for the suggestions, but do you see anythihng wrong with my method?